# Bash: loop need to continue with other entries from file ignoring failures; message for failure

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need some help to modify my script. It was written for getting the same job done for one device. I am trying to modify the script in a way so that it checks for known ssh keys in known_hosts file for a list of IP addresses. If it fails for one device, it should show the respective error and continue with the other device. I am seeding the IP addresses from a file. The code I have till now is something like following.

```
#!/bin/bash
#filename=test-file.txt
#while IFS= read -r ip in $filename
set +e
for ip in $(cat test-file.txt)
do
        echo $ip
        if [ -z "$ip" ]
        then
                echo " ERR - IP Adress not specified" #|| true
                #exit 1
        fi

        # Check if input is a valid IP address
        checkregex="[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}"
        if [[ $ip =~ $checkregex ]]
        then
                echo "OK - Input is a valid IP address" #> /dev/null 2&>1
        else
                echo "ERROR - Invalid input" #|| true
        #exit 1
        fi

        # Get linenumber and remove the key from known_hosts file
        linenumber="$(egrep -m1 -n "$ip " /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts | cut -d':' -f1)"
        i=1
        while [ $i -gt 0 ]
        do
                if [ -z "$linenumber" ]
                then
                        echo "WARN - No stored SSH key found for this device" #> /dev/null 2&>1
                        i=0
                        #exit 0
                fi
                echo "OK - SSH key found at line number ${linenumber} - Going to remove it" #> /dev/null 2&>1
                sed -i "${linenumber} d" /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts
                echo "OK - Key removed - Retry config capture on the device"
                linenumber="$(egrep -m1 -n "$ip " /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts | cut -d':' -f1)"
                if [ -z "$linenumber" ]
                then
                        echo "OK - No more stored SSH key found for this device" #> /dev/null 2&>1
                        i=0
                fi
                done
                #exit 0
done #< $filename
```

The output I am receiving is something like following.

```
xx.xx.xx.xx (IP Address)
OK - Input is a valid IP address
WARN - No stored SSH key found for this device
OK - SSH key found at line number  - Going to remove it
OK - Key removed - Retry config capture on the device
OK - No more stored SSH key found for this device
```

and it is ongoing if I comment out the exit 1 or exit 0. If I do not, it executes for the first IP in the list and exists.

I tried to modify the script in many ways but did not help much (you can see many commented entries I tried with)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Soumyadipta Ganguly

Comment: can you provide an example of the input file ?

Comment: Please  work your way thru [Before asking about problematic code](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) section of `tags/bash/info`. (And check out the **How to turn a bad script into a good question** section ain the same link). Good luck.

Comment: ***(you can see many commented entries I tried with)*** . You definitely want to abandon the `for ip in $(cat ...)` loop, and switch to  `while read filename ; do .... done < $inputile` form of looping. Also `echo "WARN ...." # > /dev/null 2>&1` and other similars makes no sense, even without the comment char. Why `>/dev/null` any Warning or Error message? Otherwise there is too much going on, so see above and make a much smaller version of your problem. You will likely fsolve it yourself!GoodLuck

Comment: The input is something like following.

xx.xx.xx.xx
yy.yy.yy.yy
zz.zz.zz.zz

Comment: `exit` will end the entire script, `break` will end the entire loop, `continue` will end the current iteration. what is your question?

Comment: I can say I got confused with exit, break and continue. Let me try with break and continue. I guess it may help.